# docker could not mount the linux destination /

Tags: docker, dockerfile

```
docker run  -v /Users/xx/var/temp:/ -it alpine bash
```

But it tips:

```
invalid mount config for type bind: invalid specification: destination can't be /
```

Why the alpine host directory could not mount?

Answer (score 8):

Docker won't permit you to bind a host directory or volume to root (`/`) inside a container.  You'll need to bind it at a subdirectory, e.g:

```
docker run -v /Users/xx/var/temp:/var/temp -it alpine bash
```

This would make the directory available at `/var/temp` inside the container.

Comment: If docker container /var/temp exists, does the host directory  /Users/xx/var/temp will override the docker container directory ?

Comment: Yes, it will hide anything that was at that path in the image.